# How to send a request to Nodejs backend server when the client closes the browser tab or window?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication

I am trying to build an application where whenever the client closes the browser window/tab I should send a notification to the backend to destroy the logged-in session and log the details of the running session. I have tried `onbeforeunload` but it is not working as intended, as it also executes on page reload. Also, it does not send the request by closing the browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no solution to do this if you do not want to destroy the session on tab reload. Also, you can't send a request on tab close. A possible solution for that would be to work with a WebSocket connection and listen for disconnect on you server and then destroy the session.